# Deploying non-linux ISO on MAAS Server

Tags: maas

I have installed MAAS server on Ubuntu 12.04.
Now I want to know that whether it is possible to 
deploy non-linux ISO images on MAAS server.

As Ubuntu Images are working; we can make it useful for 
non-tux people.

Comment: I assume the elephant in the room is an MS operating system?

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/windows-server-users-now-get-to-build-openstack-clouds-on-ubuntu-7000033206/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want non-linux virtual machines on top of OpenStack.

Remember MAAS handles the hardware and is a Ubuntu solution. Once you have MAAS you install JUJU  for orchestration and building of OpenStack. OpenStack + the hypervisor of your choice (KVM i.e.) make it feasible to install VMs similar to VMware. Of course you could use SaaS (Service as a Service) instead of VMs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry to say that is currently not supported and also not in scope for the foreseeable future.